# Need to redirect wordpress users after login and remove wp-admin toolbars and restrict access to wp-admin and profile page

Tags: wordpress

I was hoping someone could help me clean up this code or let me know if it looks okay.  It works, but I am new to php and pieced this together.  Not sure its clean enough and may impede speed.  I am trying to redirect users at login to the home page while also trying to block wp-admin and remove the toolbar at top and restrict their profile page.  I'm adding this code to my child theme functions.php

```
//Disable black bar. It will still be visible in wp-admin
if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
{
    show_admin_bar(false);
}

//Redirect from wp-admin
add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_redirect');
function my_admin_redirect()
{
    if (!defined('DOING_AJAX'))
    {
        if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
        {
            $refer=wp_get_referer();
            if (!$refer || strpos($refer, 'wp-admin'))
            {
                wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
            }
            else
            {
                wp_safe_redirect($refer);
            }
         }
    }
}

//login redirect
add_filter('login_redirect', function($url, $query, $user) {
    return home_url();
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Only suggestion for speed is that if you replace home_url(); with the actual URL of your website, given your code this would then have the same effect, but would eliminate two database calls (each instance of home_url()).

Comment: You need to add die(); after wp_safe_redirect();